# matching exact search string in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, filter, each

I'm parsing a variety of XML files using jQuery and have implemented a search function to find out of a certain word or phrase can be found in the currently selected file but am having a small problem with the line below:

```
$("LINE:contains(" + query + ")",currentContext).each(function(){
```

The search itself is working perfectly fine, however, this line is retrieving all words containing the query. For example if I want to find the word "son" it is retrieving "season".

I understand that this is down to looking for any string that contains "son". From what I have seen from looking around is that `.filter()` may solve my problem but I am unsure how to go about implementing it into my code, I tried something like `$("LINE").filter(query,currentContext).each(function()` but to no avail, so any help would be much appreciated.

A short example of one of the XML files can be viewed here : http://pastebin.com/1tqhpH4W

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not as skilled with regex as I'd like to be, but your answer is probably to use `somestring.match(/\bson\b/);`.  I'm not sure if that's exactly right, but `\b` puts a word boundary around "son", and you need something like that.

Comment: I'm the same dude, want to upskill on regex, and javascript in general, your right and @VisioN got it there, just need to wrap the query in "//b" to set the word boundary. thanks for the input dude!

Comment: yep VisioN did the heavy lifting there, I was just guessing. Glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
var word = "son";
$("LINE", currentContext).filter(function() {
    return new RegExp("\\b" + word + "\\b").test($(this).text());
}).each(function() { ... });
```

Comment: thats exactly what I needed! wasn't sure whether it would need another regex or if I could just use filter. many thanks dude!